# EnableViewStateMAC set to false, but received "Validation of viewstate MAC failed" error

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I was notified by a client that a website I am maintaining threw this error a few times in quick succession:

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

What is curious is that on every page this has been set in the directive:

```
 <%@ page language="VB" autoeventwireup="false" enableviewstatemac="false"
```

Putting to one side the question of why someone turned off ViewState MAC validation, I'm flummoxed as to how I would get a MAC validation error when it has been explicitly turned off. And, after a few errors, the page just started working again.

This ASP.Net website has just been upgraded from 2.0 to 4.5, for what it is worth.

Comment: This might help: http://www.dotnetvishal.com/2012/10/andling-validation-of-viewstate-mac.html

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?  Additionally, if the site was just upgraded from 2.0 to 4.5, it's possible that there were some existing pages in open web browsers with "stale" (2.0) view state data that couldn't be interpreted by the newer (4.5) framework.  The format of view state does sometimes change, especially between major releases.  You may also want to check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915218 for more information about resolving these errors.

Comment: Thanks, but we received the error after moving to a staging IP, so there's no possibility of a stale viewstate being cached. Am attempting to get our error log from production with the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This may occur if you are using cross page posting to different page. This was the feature introduced with .net3.5 SP1. You can find the details about this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/04/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-after-installing-net-3-5-sp1.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

MS released an update in December that forced it on: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2905247